# Kotlin async processing with optional async dependencies

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a function that conditionally fetches some data and runs some tasks concurrently on that data. Each task depends on different sets of data and I would like to avoid fetching the data that's not needed. Moreover, some of the data can have already been prefetched and given to the function. See the code I've come up with below.

```kotlin
suspend fun process(input: SomeInput, prefetchedDataX: DataX?, prefetchedDataY: DataY?) = coroutineScope {
   val dataXAsync = lazy {
       if (prefetchedDataX == null) {
           async { fetchDataX(input) }
       } else CompletableDeferred(prefetchedDataX)
   }

   val dataYAsync = lazy {
       if (prefetchedDataY == null) {
           async { fetchDataY(input) }
       } else CompletableDeferred(prefetchedDataY)
   }

   if (shouldDoOne(input)) launch {
     val (dataX, dataY) = awaitAll(dataXAsync.value, dataYAsync.value)
     val modifiedDataX = modifyX(dataX)
     val modifiedDataY = modifyY(dataY)
     doOne(modifiedDataX, modifiedDataY)
   }

   if (shouldDoTwo(input)) launch {
     val modifiedDataX = modifyX(dataXAsync.value.await())
     doTwo(modifiedDataX)
   }

   if (shouldDoThree(input)) launch {
     val modifiedDataY = modifyY(dataYAsync.value.await())
     doThree(modifiedDataY)
   }

}
```

Any improvements that could be made to this code? One, I don't like having to fakely wrap the prefetched data into a `CompletableDeferred`. Two, I don't like having to call `modifyX`, `modifyY` inside each task, I wish I could apply it at the fetching stage, but I haven't come up with a nice way to do that. Alternatively I could do

```
val modifiedDataXAsync = lazy {
   async { modifyX(prefetchedDataX ?: fetchDataX(input)) } 
}
```

but it feels wasteful to be spawning a new coroutine when the data is already prefetched. Am I over-optimizing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? This code is pretty similar to yours, I just simplified it a bit.

```
suspend fun process(input: SomeInput, prefetchedDataX: DataX?, prefetchedDataY: DataY?) = coroutineScope {

   val modifiedDataX by lazy {
       async { modifyX(prefetchedDataX ?: fetchDataX(input)) }
   }

   val modifiedDataY by lazy {
       async { modifyY(prefetchedDataY ?: fetchDataY(input)) }
   }

   if (shouldDoOne(input)) launch {
       val (dataX, dataY) = awaitAll(modifiedDataX, modifiedDataY)
       doOne(dataX, dataY)
   }

   if (shouldDoTwo(input)) launch {
       doTwo(modifiedDataX.await())
   }

   if (shouldDoThree(input)) launch {
       doThree(modifiedDataY.await())
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You can see I had a similar idea in my last code snippet. What worries me though is that we are spawning a new async coroutine even though the data is already fetched. And I don't have enough experience to judge whether that's a valid concern or just an overoptimization on my end

Comment: Coroutines are light-weight. [This](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#coroutines-are-light-weight) example on the docs creates 100k coroutines. Don't worry ;)

Comment: Exactly what I needed to hear :)